# What does “vit des femmes” mean in “Dans le quartier, on dit qu’il vit des femmes”?

Tags: sens

The question is on *vit des femmes* in the following excerpt from L'Étranger by Camus.

> Juste à ce moment est entré mon deuxième voisin de palier. Dans le quartier, on dit qu’il **vit des femmes**.

I understand from English translations that it means being a pimp or living off women, but what is the literal meaning?  And how does it come to mean what it is supposed to mean?

Here is my confusion:

- The expression may be 3rd person singular passé simple for *voir des femmes*.  But I don't find any definition for *voir* in the dictionary that would give us the intended meaning.  Also, why a past tense?
- The expression may be 3rd person singular présent for *vivre des femmes*.  Now this sounds quite poetic.  Someone can *vivre sa vie* or *vivre des femmes*.  But again no dictionary definition for this.
- Finally, I see that *vivre de qch* means living off something.  But that would give us *vit de femmes* by the rule that the indefinite article *des* is omitted after the preposition *de*.

Or perhaps there is something I have not been able to think of.

Comment: Note that *des* can also be the contraction of *de les*.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez Oh, I missed that one.  So, is that how I should read it?  "Live off *the* women"?  Or is it the more picturesque "live some women"?  The one answer so far below seems ambiguous between the two.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez Would *vivre des (de les) femmes* (literally) mean living off the womankind or all the women? Does *avoir peur des (de les) femmes* mean fearing all the women?

Comment: Yes, it means women in general. “To live off some women” would be “vivre de femmes”, but it sounds utterly wierd. There is no reason to identify a subset.

Comment: Really curious as to what you had understood from "live some women" and why you would follow that path when you had the translation which provided the verbal phrase. Why did you find it picturesque, did you read in "make alive/lively" or something along those lines?

Comment: "il" refers to a pimp that earns his life by exploitation of women. For a worker, you would write: "il vit de son travail" (*he lives from his own work*). Another French expression with "vivre de" is: "vivre d'amour et d'eau fraîche", what corresponds to the English idiom "live on love alone".

Comment: @Làchus'n'AI I didn't so much go toward "living some women" as feel barred from "living off women."  It happened because I thought "living off" was a relationship Raymond (le voisin) had with *some* women (a subset of women), not the womankind. In English it's sometimes clear which you mean.  "He loves flowers": the flowerkind.  "He brought flowers": some flowers.  But "He lived off women"? "He washes cars for a living"? I now see that it could be a reference to a relationship between the subject and a species term.

Comment: As for picturesque meaning, I imagined the French language gradually extending the range of things that can be said to be "lived":  from life to a dream or nightmare, then a trade, then perhaps the objects of a trade? All this from firmly (and rather unconsciously) rejecting *des* as contraction of *de les* (because, again, le voisin exploited only *some* women).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The verb in the sentence here is indeed *vivre*. Comments by Catonic, Stéphane, Graffito and SF_user are all true in a way.

So in this context, *il vit des femmes* indeed means he lives off (some - those of the neighbourhood for example, acquaintances of his...) women. This is not the same as *il vit de femmes*, which does seem weird.

As a French, the immediate meaning I get from *il vit de femmes* is "he lives on women", that is, he satiates basic physiological needs (either he eats them, or has lustful, indiscriminate sex with them for example, which galanterie forbids). The correct English translation of Camus' sentence would be in this case "he lives off women" as SF_user points out. A way to paraphrase that in French would be *il est entretenu par des femmes*.

Another nuance in using *des femmes* instead of *de femmes* is that Camus is not specific about which particular women, but not entirely unspecific altogether: he is not saying he is living off womankind. He means the protagonist:

- is living off *some* women - he does not really care which one in particular
- yet he is not living off **any** woman in the world: it has to be women he knows, neighbours, relatives...

Please note the importance of context here: the reader at this point has an idea of which women Camus is talking about. It is perfectly correct and not weird to say : *il vit de petits larcins* (he lives off petty crime). In this case, I understand he is not directly sating basic needs, but that he is involved in a fishy business to get some money somewhere. On the contrary, if someone said *il vit des petits larcins*, it would seem weird: which ones? It would translate as "he lives off the petty crimes", and would seem strange.

Last, you are correct: *il vit* may be 3rd person singular passé simple for voir des femmes.
*voir des femmes* would then mean "he dates some women, he meets some women on a regular basis, and rather casually".
Here, both context and tense are crucially important.
- In French, passé simple denotes a brief action, well situated in time. For example, we could use it to underline an extraordinary situation, such as *il vit une très belle femme* or *il vit un très gros chien*. So using *voir* meaning "to date, on a casual, somewhat lengthy basis" with passé simple does not fit. We would use imparfait in this case, and say, "il voyait des femmes", all the more so because passé simple belongs to the written language and is very formal, whereas *voir des femmes* is quite casual.

Comment: See also the expression "_vivre des femmes_" directly in the [_TLFi_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vivre) and the interesting entry for the familiar use of [_gigolo_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gigolo), not the same as the [_proxénète_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/proxenete) indeed. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

In this novel, the person designed by `il` dans `on dit qu’il vit des femmes.` is Sintès.

And after reading this novel, it is clear Sintès lives off women. In other words, he uses women to live, women pay for his living, he lives at the expense of women.

So in conclusion, the verb used in this sentence is *Vivre*.