# Understanding "Il lui donnait juste de quoi vivre"

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, syntaxe

The question on the highlighted sentence from this excerpt from L'Étranger by Camus.

> En mangeant, il a commencé à me raconter son histoire. Il hésitait d’abord un peu. « J’ai connu une dame… c’était pour autant dire ma maîtresse. » L’homme avec qui il s’était battu était le frère de cette femme. Il m’a dit qu’il l’avait entretenue. Je n’ai rien répondu et pourtant il a ajouté tout de suite qu’il savait ce qu’on disait dans le quartier, mais qu’il avait sa conscience pour lui et qu’il était magasinier.
>        « Pour en venir à mon histoire, m’a-t-il dit, je me suis aperçu qu’il y avait de la tromperie. » **Il lui donnait juste de quoi vivre.** Il payait lui-même le loyer de sa chambre et il lui donnait vingt francs par jour pour la nourriture.

Question:  How does *lui donner juste de quoi vivre* come to mean what it means?

There it is, but I am afraid you could not understand what it's really about without reading what follows.  I am sorry I cannot condense this question.

**Background**

When I first saw *de quoi vivre*, I thought it was my old friend *vivre de* from [the previous question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16640/vit-des-femme-in-dans-le-quartier-on-dit-qu-il-vit-des-femmes).  If so, we have a nice, almost word-per-word correspondence between these sentences:

> Il lui donnait juste **de** quoi vivre.
>   He gave her just what to live **on**.

The only difference is that a French infinitive does not need anything like *to* to set if off and that *de* (unlike English *on*) moved up.  But consider:

> As-tu de quoi écrire?

According to [this dictionary entry](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/quoi), that means, "Have you got anything to write with?"  But *write with* is *écrire avec*.  So what happened?  Something like this perhaps?

> As-tu + de quoi + écrire **avec** > (As-tu + **avec** + de quoi + écrire) > As-tu + de quoi + écrire.

Namely, *de quoi* is a unit in its own right and a suppression of *avec* took place (with or without an intervening step of transposition).

Then maybe the same thing happened to our friend *vivre de*.

> Il lui donnait juste + de quoi + vivre **de** > (Il lui donnait juste + **de** + de quoi + vivre) > Il lui donnait juste + de quoi + vivre.

Namely, the surviving *de* did not come from *vivre de* but from *de quoi*.

Another expression *avoir de quoi faire*, from [this dictionary entry](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/quoi), seems to suggest further awesome powers of *de quoi*.  *To have to do something* is ordinarily *avoir à faire*, but:

> avoir **à** + de quoi + faire > avoir + de quoi + faire

Namely, *de quoi* caused a suppression of *à*.  (Of course, I am not saying this is what happened, only that I am trying to find an explanation.)

To restate the question, I want to know whether *Il lui donnait juste de quoi vivre* comes to mean what it does through either of the two routes above (word-per-word correspondence vs. suppression of *de* in *vivre de*) or in some other way I have not been able to think of.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case,*de quoi* is a relative substantive clause (**relative substantive** in French or **relative sans antécédent**). It complements the verb *donner* in the sentence

> Il lui donnait juste de quoi vivre.

According to *Grammaire méthodique du français* by Martin Riegel, Jean-Christophe Pellat and René Rioul, relative substantive clauses are introduced by a pronoun, here *quoi*, which has to be preceded by a preposition, in this case *de*, since the relative pronoun is a non-animated object (money, a flat, food for example). Moreover, the tense verb of the relative clause *vivre*, is infinitif, since *donner* is a transitive verb. The tense has to be infinitif if the relative is preceded by *il y a*, such as in

> Il y a de quoi manger.
>   Il y a de quoi rire.

About the first example you mention,

> As-tu de quoi écrire ?
>   *avec* is omitted, because it is obvious the object denoted by the relative pronoun is to be used to write *with* (paper, ink, pen...).

Regarding your second comment (the disappearance of one *de*), it is known in French as *la règle de cacophonie*, namely, that repeating de/des would not be very pleasant to hear or utter, mentionned in *[la Grammaire générale et raisonnée](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port-Royal_Grammar)* de Port-Royal :

> de des, et encore plus de de, eût trop choqué l'oreille, et elle eût peine à souffrir qu'on eût dit : *il est accusé de des crimes horribles*, ou, *il est accusé de de grands crimes*.

*avoir à faire* is indeed the correct way to say *to have something to do*. We would less laconically say *avoir quelque chose à faire* to mean the same thing.

*Il y a de quoi faire*, *j'ai de quoi faire* is rather a casual expression, with an  underlying nuance of awe, admiration, annoyance... See for example http://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/37467.

For example, we could say in front of a gargantuesque quantity of food during *le réveillon de Noël*:

> eh beh, il y a de quoi faire !

implying, wow, such a great quantity of good-smelling food!
Or when having to clean the mess after the dog wreaked havoc in the living room:

> Purée, il y a de quoi faire !

or before undertaking a long, straining task,

> Il y a de quoi faire !

Note that it differs from expressions such as:

> J'ai de quoi faire parler cet homme

for example, meaning in this case I have means to make this man talk.

Comment: Nice answer +1.  If you don’t mind, I have a, perhaps unrelated, follow-up question: In the OP’s example (“Il lui donnait juste de quoi vivre”), could “**pour** [vivre]” be correctly added here or would its addition create a different meaning/nuance (or even worse, would its addition simply be incorrect) (ie, “Il lui donnait juste de quoi **pour** vivre.”)?   Thanks!

Comment: In this case, it seems redundant. _pour_ is also a preposition, introducing what we call in French a _complément circonstanciel de but_, which is the verb _vivre_: it precices the circomstances by adding a sense of goal, of purpose to the sentence. For example, _j'étudie pour réussir_: I study to be successful.

The preposition _quoi_ in _juste de quoi vivre_ rather underlines the means by which this person is sustained, even though not specifically mentionned (money, a rented room...).

To put the emphasis on both, one could say _il lui donnait juste de quoi vivre, juste assez pour vivre._

Comment: Thank you. I have follow-up questions too. (1) If *avec* in *écrire avec* is deleted as "obvious and unnecessary" then do we need a second principle (i.e. cacophonie) for deleting *de* in *vivre de*? In other words, I wonder if there wouldn't be a single principle that explains all the similar deletions.

Comment: (2) As a beginning French student, I would not have thought *avec* was obvious without actually being there. Once I recognize *de quoi* as a unit (relative pronoun) then *As-tu de quoi écrire?* looks to me like:  "Do you have anything to write, perhaps a poem, a letter, a constitution?" Maybe I should ask how one would say in French, "Do you have anything to write?"

Comment: In this case, think that _quoi_ denotes means to accomplish the action, not the goal or the purpose.
The correct way to express "Do you have anything to write (about)?" would be _As-tu quelque chose à écrire ?_

Comment: The correct way to express "Do you have anything to write (about)?" would be _As-tu quelque chose à écrire ?

_à_ rather stresses the action itself, instead of the means to accomplish it. For example: _as-tu à faire_: "do you have something to do?". In this case, I am concerned if he has something that is likely to keep him busy, I do not care how he will actually do it.

Other examples:
(1) As-tu à peindre ? --> is the action of painting necessary? For example, to refurbish a flat, or to draw for school...
(2) As-tu de quoi peindre ? --> do you have the right tools? brush, paper, pencils...?

Comment: Regarding your first comment, it amounts to the same I would say. The idea is not to make sentences too convoluted or redundant (we already have many occasions to do that in French). So in this case _avec_ is omitted since preposition _quoi_ already denotes the means. It would be redundant with _avec_, though it is not grammatically incorrect to say _as-tu de quoi écrire avec ?_

Answer (score 0):

Il lui donnait juste de quoi vivre.

**Literally:** He him gave just *(1)* of what to live.

*(1) Understand "just enough".*